# How do I estimate Fanatic progress?

Tags: discussion, data-dump, activity-badges, badge-progress

Do the data dumps have breadcrumbs other than posts and comments?

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use Time::Local;
```

Count daily activity in `$seen{$date}`:

```
my %seen;
```

Count comments and posts or edits:

```
sub comments {
  my($id) = @_;
  open my $fh, "<", "comments.xml" or die "$0: open: $!";
  while (<$fh>) {
    next unless /UserId="$id"/;
    die "$0: $.: no CreationDate"
      unless /CreationDate="(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T.*?"/;
    ++$seen{$1};
  }
}

sub posts {
  my($id) = @_;
  open my $fh, "<", "posts.xml" or die "$0: open: $!";
  while (<$fh>) {
    if (/OwnerUserId="$id"/) {
      die "$0: $.: no CreationDate"
        unless /CreationDate="(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T.*?"/;
      ++$seen{$1};
    }
    elsif (/LastEditorUserId="$id"/) {
      die "$0: $.: no LastEditDate"
        unless /LastEditDate="(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})T.*?"/;
      ++$seen{$1};
    }
  }
}
```

Finally the tally:

```
sub as_time_t {
  my($date) = @_;
  die "$0: bad date '$date'"
    unless /^(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)$/;
  timegm 0, 0, 0, $3, $2-1, $1-1900;
}

die "Usage: $0 id-num\n" unless @ARGV == 1;
my $id = qr/\Q$ARGV[0]/;
comments $id;
posts    $id;

my($start,$end) = map as_time_t($_), (sort keys %seen)[0,-1];
for (my $t = $start; $t < $end; $t += 86_400) {
  my($mday,$mon,$year) = (gmtime $t)[3,4,5];
  $seen{ sprintf "%04d-%02d-%02d" => $year+1900, $mon+1, $mday } += 0;
}

my $streak = 0;
foreach my $date (sort keys %seen) {
  if ($seen{$date}) {
    ++$streak;
    printf "%4d - $date - $seen{$date}\n", $streak;
  }
  else {
    $streak = 0;
  }
}
```

Example usage:

```
$ cd "Stack Overflow Data Dump - Feb 10/Content/022010 SO"
$ streak 22656
[...]
 149 - 2010-01-27 - 38
 150 - 2010-01-28 - 17
 151 - 2010-01-29 - 25
 152 - 2010-01-30 - 17
 153 - 2010-01-31 - 7
```

Comment: How does someone who isn't even sure what language this is, could use your scripts? Care to add a little explanation?

Comment: @Downvoter It's a single Perl program broken up with commentary to avoid scrolling. Run it in, for example, `.../Stack Overflow Data Dump - Feb 10/Content/022010 SO`.

Comment: To clarify, since this wasn't at all obvious to me: You need to run this Perl script from within the data dump directory. It takes your user id as a command-line argument. It identifies days where you made 1 or more comments, posts or edits. It prints 'streak' - date - number of contributions. 'streak' is a number which increments for each consecutive day you've made a contribution without a break.

Comment: is it possible to run that script on some online service which allows running perl script?

Answer (score 23):

Has your spouse left you or complained about the amount of time spent on SO? Been reprimanded for using SO at work?  If so, you're well on your way to the Fanatic badge.

Answer (score 10):

This used to be a great question — I installed perl just to run that script — but  it's past its expiration date.

The answer: to estimate your progress towards the Fanatic badge, go to your profile and look at the "consecutive days" count; you just need to visit for the next `100 - currentConsecutiveDays` days in a row.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder why someone hasn't set up a webservice that "visits" SO daily on behalf of users that sign up for it.

<sub>/classy</sub>

Comment: It's called "Safari Top Sites" -- open browser, visit SO and Meta, voilà!

Comment: @tvanfosson: That's actually quite annoying. By automatically visiting SO it might hide the notification that I've got new rep or comments.

Comment: Those don't typically disappear until you click the close button or do the action they've suggested.  Anyway, I'm not suggesting that it should be done, just commenting that it works that way for me without even trying.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing November 15th, so work it out from there ;-p