# For How many continuous days i have been using SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Consecutive Day Count in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/865/consecutive-day-count-in-profile)

Hello,

Is there a way to see that for how many **continuous days** i have been using/visiting the stack overflow site? Any:

- way possible to know that
- any script out there
- any greasmonkey script

I mean **days** not months.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [perl script](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39221/how-do-i-estimate-fanatic-progress) to estimate fanatic badge (which is 100 continuous days) on data dump.

Comment: +1: Thanks for that info, but i wonder how do i run that script, no clear explantion there. It would be great if i could run that script on some online service offering to run perl script.

Comment: @Sarfraz, To run that, you need to have perl and data dump, try it in linux box. And yes, if there is online service, that would be great.