# How many days are yet to go for fanatic badge?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I estimate Fanatic progress?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39221/how-do-i-estimate-fanatic-progress)

question is tag line

Comment: Duplicate of http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39221/how-do-i-estimate-fanatic-progress and, I think, a couple other questions.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34432/electorate-badge-progress-pundit-etc-too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm..... one way you might track it is to make sure you get a reputation change *every day*, and then you could track it with the reputation script:

https://stackoverflow.com/reputation

One way you could ensure a reputation change every day would be to do a single downvote every day.